# How do I change date time format in Android?

Tags: android

I am displaying the date and time in Android with this format:
**2013-06-18 12:41:24**

How can I change it to the following format?
**18-jun-2013 12:41 pm**

Comment: can u post ur sample code for getting datetime?

Comment: What about `MMM-dd-yyyy  hh:mm a`? Did you tried yourself?

Comment: i'm getting the date and time in sqllite database

Comment: @AnilMH post ur get datetime code from sqllite!

Comment: lv_formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-mm-dd HH:mm:ss");
   lv_formatter.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getDefault());

Answer (score 106, accepted):

Here is working code

```
public String parseDateToddMMyyyy(String time) {
    String inputPattern = "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss";
    String outputPattern = "dd-MMM-yyyy h:mm a";
    SimpleDateFormat inputFormat = new SimpleDateFormat(inputPattern);
    SimpleDateFormat outputFormat = new SimpleDateFormat(outputPattern);

    Date date = null;
    String str = null;

    try {
        date = inputFormat.parse(time);
        str = outputFormat.format(date);
    } catch (ParseException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return str;
}
```

Documentation: [SimpleDateFormat | Android Developers](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html)

Answer (score 6):

```
    SimpleDateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MMM-yyyy  hh:mm a");
    String date = format.format(Date.parse("Your date string"));
```

Comment: i'm getting the date and time in sql ,i can pass to "Your date string"

Comment: Even if you retrieve the date in Sql, you have an object Date.
So you can use the method toString() :
String date = format.format(Date.parse(sqlDate.toString()));

Answer (score 5):

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    private Date oneWayTripDate;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        String date ="2017-05-05 13:58:50 ";
        SimpleDateFormat input = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss");
        SimpleDateFormat output = new SimpleDateFormat("MMMM dd,yyyy @hh:mm:ss aa");
        try {
            oneWayTripDate = input.parse(date);  // parse input
        } catch (ParseException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
       }
       Log.e("===============","======currentData======"+output.format(oneWayTripDate);
    }
}
```

Comment: This doesn't look like giving the desired date format at all.

Answer (score 5):

I modified Rusabh's answer for general purpose formatting of date in my project

```
    public String formatDate(String dateToFormat, String inputFormat, String outputFormat) {
        try {
            Logger.e("DATE", "Input Date Date is " + dateToFormat);

            String convertedDate = new SimpleDateFormat(outputFormat)
                    .format(new SimpleDateFormat(inputFormat)
                            .parse(dateToFormat));

            Logger.e("DATE", "Output Date is " + convertedDate);

            //Update Date
            return convertedDate;

        } catch (ParseException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return null;

    }
```

**Usage:**

```
            String inputFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mmz";
            String OutPutFormat = "MMMM dd', 'yyyy hh:mma";
            String convertedDate = formatDate(asOfDateTime, inputFormat, OutPutFormat);
```

Comment: Please don’t teach the young ones to use `SimpleDateFormat` as the first option and without any reservation. I know it’s what comes built in on not-quite-new Android, but it’s also an outdated and notoriously troublesome class. Today we have so much better in [`java.time`, the modern Java date and time API,](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/) and its `DateTimeFormatter`. Yes, you can use on lower API level Android too when you add [ThreeTenABP](https://github.com/JakeWharton/ThreeTenABP) to your Android programming project.

Answer (score 4):

Use this code like below:

```
SimpleDateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MMM-yyyy hh:mm a");
String date = formatter.format(Date.parse("Your date string"));
```

Hope it will help you.

Comment: i'm getting the date and time in sql ,i can pass to "Your date string"

Answer (score 2):

You have to set like this

```
 Date date=new Date("Your date "); 
SimpleDateFormat formatter5=new SimpleDateFormat("required format");
String formats1 = formatter5.format(date);
System.out.println(formats1);
```

Answer (score 2):

set answer like this to set date format

```
 Date date=new Date("Your date "); 
SimpleDateFormat formatter5=new SimpleDateFormat("required format");
```

Answer (score 1):

use this code below:

```
Date date=new Date("2013-06-18 12:41:24"); 
SimpleDateFormat formatter5=new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MM-yyyy hh:mm a");
String formats1 = formatter5.format(date);
System.out.println(formats1);
```

Answer (score 0):

First Create a `Calendar` object using your `Date` object. Then build a `String` using date, year, month and etc you need. then you can use it.

You can get data using [get()](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/Calendar.html#get%28int%29) method in `Calendar` class.

Answer (score 0):

We can use this format for convert the date. Pass the date as parameter

```
  public String formatdate(String fdate)
{
    String datetime=null;
    DateFormat inputFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MM-yyyy");
    SimpleDateFormat d= new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");
    try {
        Date convertedDate = inputFormat.parse(fdate);
        datetime = d.format(convertedDate);

    }catch (ParseException e)
    {

    }
    return  datetime;


}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
private val dateFormatter: Format = SimpleDateFormat(
    android.text.format.DateFormat.getBestDateTimePattern(
        Locale.getDefault(),
        "dMMyyjjmmss"
    ),
    Locale.getDefault()
)

val dateText = dateFormatter.format(Date(System.currentTimeMillis()))
```

This is the best choice available on Android which will format time based on device default Locate

Example output depending on Locale:

- USA - `02/18/2021, 1:00:00 PM` (USA uses 12 format time)
- Ukraine -     `18.2.2012, 13:00:00` (Ukraine uses 24 format time)

So it does all the hard job automatically for you

P.S. replace `yy` with `yyyy` if you need 2021 instead of 21, `MM` to `MMM` if you want display month as word instead of number and so on

For example `"dMMMyyyyjjmmss"` for USA will return:

`Feb 18, 2021, 1:43:20 PM`

For Russia:

`18 февр. 2021 г., 13:44:18`

Amazing, isn't?

Answer (score 0):

In case if you're using Kotlin and not JAVA then you can use this function and paste it inside your Utils class so that you can directly use this to show date in String.

```
fun getFormatedDate(dateToFormat: String, inputFormat: String, outputFormat: String): String {
        try {
            val inputDateTimeFormat = SimpleDateFormat(inputFormat, Locale.getDefault())
            inputDateTimeFormat.timeZone = TimeZone.getTimeZone("UTC")
            val date: Date? = inputDateTimeFormat.parse(dateToFormat)
            return if (null != date) {
                SimpleDateFormat(outputFormat, Locale.getDefault()).format(date)
            } else {
                ""
            }
        } catch (e: ParseException) {
            e.printStackTrace()
        }
        return ""
    }
```

and call this function just by

```
getFormatedDate(yourInputStringDate,
                    "dd MM yyyy HH:mm:ss Z",
                    "MMM dd yyyy HH:mm")
```

where you "yourInputStringDate" is your dateTime in String

Comment: I strongly recommend that you use [java.time, the modern Java date and time API,](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/index.html) in Kotlin. If for older Android, then through core library desugaring. `SimpleDateFormat` was a notorious troublemaker of a class and fortunately supplanted by java.time a decade ago  Same for `TimeZone` and `Date`.

Comment: From your code I get *Unresolved reference: formatDate*. When I change to `getFormatedDate` and set `yourInputStringDate` to the string from the question, `2013-06-18 12:41:24`, I get `ParseException: Unparseable date: "2013-06-18 12:41:24"`.

Comment: @OleV.V. updated the answer!

Comment: You are still using the terrible old classes. And i still get the same exception.

Comment: @OleV.V. you have to check your date format first. In this answer, the date format is different than yours. You must find your date format from https://developer.android.com/reference/android/icu/text/SimpleDateFormat and then use this solution. Also, it's not terrible old classes until it's deprecated, you can use it. And, it's an official solution recommended by Google. Also, JAVA is not an official language now, so your first comment is irrelevant.