# getDateTimeInstance 24 hours style

Tags: java, date-format, simpledateformat

I want to get the date in 24 hours format but can't find anything.

i tried this with no luck:

```
System.out.println(DateFormat.getDateTimeInstance(DateFormat.SHORT, DateFormat.SHORT).format(Calendar.getInstance().getTime()));
```

but it prints
28/05/14 03:57 PM

instead of
28/05/14 15:57

how can i print the hour without the AM/PM and in 24 hours format?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[DateFormat.getDateTimeInstance()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/text/DateFormat.html#getDateTimeInstance-int-int-java.util.Locale-) can also have three arguments. The third argument specifies the region where certain customs like time formats are common (if 24-hour-style in most countries or rather am/pm-style like in US).

By choosing an explicit locale you can control the behaviour of your format-object in a locale-dependent way. Internally Java will choose the right format pattern for you given the informations about date style, time style and locale.

If this is not sufficient you might consider `SimpleDateFormat` instead. Then you yourself decide which exact format pattern to choose, but this is fixed then. You might also consider a combination of both approaches if you are not satisfied with what Java sees as right format for given locale but also want to have a localized solution:

```
DateFormat df;

if (locale.equals(myLocale)) {
  df = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yy HH:mm"); // yy for 2-digit-year, not YY!
} else {
  // general solution for other locales
  df = DateFormat.getDateTimeInstance(DateFormat.SHORT, DateFormat.SHORT, myLocale);
}
```

Comment: on some  Xiaomi and Huawei devices third parameter doesn't help at all, always 12 format time

Comment: @user924 Have you also tested for `Locale.GERMANY` (de_DE) which should always produce the 24-hour-style? If this test fails then it is a problem with the device text resources resp. Android installation.

Comment: the best solution I found is `SimpleDateFormat(DateFormat.getBestDateTimePattern(Locale.getDefault(), "dMMyyjjmmss"), Locale.getDefault())`, it automatically will use MM/dd/yy or dd.MM.yy and other depending on default `Locale` and will use 12 (including a.m., p.m prefix at the end) or 24 format

Comment: stop.. I guess the question about just java, so comment can be off topic here (related to Android)

Comment: answered here (related to Android) https://stackoverflow.com/a/66259102/7767664

Answer (score 2):

The [answer by Meno Hochschild](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23921456/642706) is correct.

FYI, here is the same kind of solution but using [Joda-Time](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/) 2.3.

```
DateTimeZone timeZone = DateTimeZone.forID( "America/Montreal" ); // Specify a time zone rather than rely on default.
DateTime now = DateTime.now( timeZone );
```

Generate a String representation in the sensible [ISO 8601](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601) format. This standard uses 24-hour clock.

```
String outputIso = now.toString();
```

Generate a String representation in a localized format.

```
java.util.Locale locale = java.util.Locale.CANADA_FRENCH;
DateTimeFormatter formatter = DateTimeFormat.forStyle( "SS" ).withLocale( locale );
String outputQuébécois = formatter.print( now );
```

Generate exactly the format you specified.

```
DateTimeFormatter formatter = DateTimeFormat.forPattern( "dd/MM/yy HH:mm" ); // See note about year in answer by Meno Hochschild.
String output = formatter.print( now );
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to use a [SimpleDateFormat](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html) object.

The string you want is "dd/MM/YY HH:mm"

```
SimpleDateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/YY HH:mm");
Date myFormattedDate = dateFormat.parse(myUnformattedDate);
System.out.println(myFormattedDate.toString());
```