# Java Regex : How to skip in between text while forming groups?

Tags: java, regex

How can i parse "dd-MM-yyyy hh:mm:ss" from following multiline entry ?

```
Data:11-11-2011
Time:01:01:00
```

1) So as to parse "11-11-2011 T 01:01:00" we can use simple date format as "dd-MM-yyyy 'T' hh:mm:ss".
But how can we introduce '\n' char in above mentioned example ?

2) Or else please help me defining a java REGEX pattern, which will evaluate to "11-11-2011 01:01:00" and will ignore the "newline and Time:" string in above example.

Answer (score 0):

Easiest way would be just to use `StringBuilder` to append two values and remove that `Data:` and `Time:` texts.

You would get first:

`Data:11-11-2011 Time:01:01:00`

And then

`11-11-2011 01:01:00`

Then use SimpleFormatData to parse current time https://stackoverflow.com/a/17291726/619673

Comment: Can't do any java code in my system, i am providing a string to parse and the simple date format from web based UI.
Also, don't want to change any java side code.

Comment: does it mean you have something like: `Data:11-11-2011\nTime:01:01:00`? What is the real structure of your string?

Comment: so it changes everything... Please edit your problem to proper structure of string..

Comment: i have modified the question as per your suggestion