# How to store date as 18/12/2016 in date datatype

Tags: android, date

I am trying to store the value of date as 18/12/2016 into a date variable..

For example

```
    Date date=new Date(); 
    SimpleDateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy");
    Date theDate = null;

    try {
        theDate = dateFormat.parse(date.toString());
        System.out.println("Date parsed = " + dateFormat.format(theDate));
    } catch (ParseException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

But the above code gives an error

```
java.text.ParseException: Unparseable date: "Mon Jun 18 00:00:00 IST 2012"
```

I have found examples where we can change the format and store it in the string datatype.
But I need an example where we can store it in the date format itself.

Hope you guys understand my question.Please help..

Thanks.

EDIT-All the links given shows how to store the date into a string.I need to store the date in the format 18/12/2016 inside the date datatype itself.So it is not a duplicate Question.

Comment: Your date containing white space in place of "/" symbol and also having time with zone. This is reason you getting "Unparseable" error.

Comment: Check this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17290916/how-to-change-the-date-format-in-android

Comment: You didn't passed any date. So system is trying to convert some default date.

Comment: but in that link the output is in string...I need it in date datatype..Is that possible??

Comment: @Gowrishankar  Date date=new Date(); gives the current date..But it is in the format  "Mon Jun 18 00:00:00 IST 2012" and I need it as 18/06/2012

Comment: @thepoosh  How can his be a duplicate??I am not using any string variables to store the date.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9872419/how-to-convert-a-string-to-a-date-using-simpledateformat

Answer (score 0):

No need to parse it. just format it when you want show the date.

```
SimpleDateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy");
Date theDate = new Date();

try {
     System.out.println("Date parsed = " + dateFormat.format(theDate));
} catch (ParseException e) {
     e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Comment: I don't want to show the date...I need to save the date in the date datatype and pass it to the server.

Comment: no you cant. date datatype have its own format to keep the data. so, you must send date to server as a string instead of date

Comment: oh...thanks anyway...

Answer (score 0):

even though I think this is duplicated by [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10426492/change-date-string-format-in-android) I will answer in short.

`SimpleDateFormatter` is a way to display dates and not to store them, all dates should be stored and handled in a number format referring to UTC in order to prevent mistakes.

A fun side note is [this youtube video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=-5wpm-gesOY) about dealing with time that ephesises the need to deal with time in a unified way and then only format it to the users in the UI level.

Answer (score 0):

ou are wrong in the way you display the data I guess, because for me:

```
String dateString = "18/12/2016";
SimpleDateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy");
Date convertedDate = new Date();
try {
    convertedDate = dateFormat.parse(dateString);
} catch (ParseException e) {
    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
    e.printStackTrace();
}
System.out.println(convertedDate);
```

Comment: convertedDate gives the value "Mon Jun 18 00:00:00 GMT+05:30 2012"